# abstract class constructor practical use

Tags: java, object, constructor, abstract-class, instantiation

Can we have constructor in abstract class ?

If yes, what the use of that because we can't instantiate the Abstract class and constructor will never call.

Comment: "Constructor" is not really good name. It suggests that it is responsible for constructing (creating) object, but it is not really true. `new` keyword is responsible for creating (uninitialized) object, constructor code is responsible for *initializing* (setting up) that object. So constructor in abstract class is part of initialization process only, which can be part of constructing *subclass* instance.

Comment: Rohit - Don't get the impression from Pshemo's comment above that **you've** used the term incorrectly. You haven't. It's just that the term itself is slightly-incorrect when viewed from a Java (or several other languages) perspective, `initializer` would have been a better term (for the reasons he/she gives). But it's not the term that got used. :-)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The implementing class can call it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

For inheritance. So the sub class can use it.